# Taylor's theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to understand how to use Taylor's theorem. The theorem states the following: "Let $k ≥ 1$ be an integer and let the function $f : R → R$ be $k$ times differentiable at the point $a ∈ R$. Then there exists a function $h_k : R → R$ such that: $f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2 + ... + \frac{f^{(k)}}{k!}(x-a)^k + h_k(x)(x-a)^k$ and $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow +\infty}(h_k(x))=0$

How would I use that formula practically for sin(x) and cos(x) for example?
How would I determine $h_k(x)$?

Comment: Do you want to determine $h_k(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the $k$th Taylor polynomial of $f$ at $a$ by $T_k(x)$. Then the theorem says that there is a function $h_k$, continuous and vanishing at $a$, such that
$$f(x)=T_k(x)+h_k(x)(x-a)^k\ .\tag{1}$$
From $(1)$ one infers that for $x\ne a$ the function $h$ is given by
$$h(x)={f(x)-T_k(x)\over(x-a)^k}\ ,$$
and converges to $0$ when $x\to a$. Now this function $h$ is not interesting per se, and nobody would want to know its exact values. The essential point is the following: We are **guaranteed** that  near $a$ the approximation error $f(x)-T_k(x)$ is "by orders of magnitude" smaller than the already small quantity $(x-a)^k$.

Answer (score 0):

To find the taylor-series for $sin(x)$ at $a=0$, note that the derivations are $cos(x),-sin(x),-cos(x),sin(x)$ and at this point, you can see that the functions repeat periodically.

So, the derivates at $a=0$ are (beginning with the $0$'th) : $0,1,0,-1,0,1,0,-1,...$, so you get $$sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}\pm...$$ and analogue calculations lead to $$cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}\pm...$$

Comment: why didn't you determine $h_k(x)$